# How to get a clean CDT Build Console Output?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, console, eclipse-cdt, verbosity

I'm working with STM32CubeIDE using gcc compiler. In the build output I have to search for warnings and errors in a hundred lines of compiler-output infos. I'm explicitly interested in all warnings and errors! But I do not need something like this as there isn't any warning or error:

(Useful information)
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../gmem/wdog.c"

(followed by 912 useless bytes)
-mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DNUCLEO -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F446xx -DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER -c -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/Ampel" -I../Core/Inc -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/lcd" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/rtc" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/so" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/uart" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/interrupts" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/gmem" -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/debugpins" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/funk" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/kabel" -I"E:/STM32CubeIDE_11/fatl22_lcd/scheduler" -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wconversion -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"gmem/wdog.d" -MT"gmem/wdog.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "gmem/wdog.o"

How can I get rid of this crap ?

I searched for gcc option help files and some "how to increase verbosity" hoping to find the contrary ;-) .
I found explicit help for reducing warnings, which is not my intention.